# Choose among more .txt

Tags: c++, string

I'm working on a project and I need to select a different .txt every time based on the input.

This is what I have:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <time.h>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
#include <stdio.h>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
string hp, att, def, vel, spec;
string answer, monster;

do
{
    cout << "Which Monster?: ";
    cin >> monster;
    cout << endl;

    ifstream selection;
    selection.open(monster+".txt");

    selection.close();

    cout << endl << "Again? ";
    cin >> answer;
}
while (answer == "y");

cout << "Hello world!" << endl;
return 0;
}
```

I have to get the monster string and search the .txt with the same name.
If I type "Troll" it will search for the Troll.txt
Is there a way?

This is the error I get:
F:\GdR\Campagna 1\CalcoloStats\main.cpp|22|error: no matching function for call to 'std::basic_ifstream::open(std::__cxx11::basic_string)'|

Comment: Typo; `"txt"` -> `".txt"`

Comment: @Capoz: Could you please take some time to improve [that other question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/52026886/841108) from you? It needs to be edited and improved.

Answer (score 1):

Given that `monster` is a `std::string`, this expression:

```
 monster + ".txt"
```

is also a `std::string`.

Since C++11, you can use this as an argument to `ifstream`'s `open` function just fine. However, until then, you are stuck with a limitation of `ifstream` which is that it can only take a C-style string.

Fortunately, you can get a C-style string from a `std::string` using the `c_str()` member function.

So, either:

```
selection.open((monster + "txt").c_str());
```

Or get a modern compiler / switch out of legacy mode.

Answer (score -1):

Thanks Lightness Races in Orbit, solved with C++11 Compiler flag

Comment: What compiler flag? Can you please elaborate?

Comment: This is not an answer to your question