# Save data in the .exe file

Tags: c++11, exe

Is there a way to create a console application program that asks input data (eg users birth dates, favourite food, everything) and does anything i program it to do and keep those data stored in that .exe when i close it?

This way, when I'll open it again, all those datas will still be saved there, so I just have to update or modify them.

Comment: First problem you're going to have is trying to write into a file currently being used -- as it is the .exe itself being run at the moment... You'll need to acquire the appropriate privileges.

Comment: Are you on windows? If so it has [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/winbase/nf-winbase-updateresourcea). But it's kind of hard to think of a scenario where you'll want to actually do that instead of a separate file. Can you specify more on the use-case here?

Comment: Why should the data be stored inside the `.exe` -and not elsehwere- as every programs do? What should happen if your program is running in different processes simultaneously?

Comment: You will open a gateway for virus attacks.

Comment: Please **edit your question** to add motivations for that weird (and perhaps even unreasonable) requirement. Why don't you want an installation procedure, like most software have?

Comment: Without motivation and details (what OS, what compiler, what program) your question is unclear. So I am voting to close it. You really should take time to improve it. So please **edit your question**

Comment: Very confusing question. If you just want to keep birthdays and food preference, you just need some database. If you aim a self-generating system, you should explicitly tell that! I'm waiting for you to improve and motivate your question!

Comment: Your question smells very *badly* as some [XY problem](http://xyproblem.info).... **What is your actual problem?** : managing birth dates and food preferences, or (against every reasonable practice) indeed generate an executable with new data? Why do you want to do that? Why can't you follow common practices? Why do you tag C++11 (and don't mention your OS and compiler; they are extremely relevant)? I'm still hoping for you to improve and motivate your question !

Comment: I am still waiting for you to improve your question. I took time to provide two answers. Could you, as a courtesy to readers, improve your question (follow the `edit` link) and add a few much needed paragraphs on context and motivation (what is your *real* problem?).

Answer (score 5):

## Don't save data *inside* your [executable](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Executable) but outside of it

> Is there a way to create a [...] program that asks input data [...] then keep those data stored in that .exe when i close it?

There is no simple way (but you don't need that). What you want is related to [persistence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Persistence_(computer_science)) and [application checkpointing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Application_checkpointing).

In practice, you probably want to store data in a file -not your executable- (perhaps using some textual format like [JSON](http://json.org/)) or in some [database](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database) (perhaps as simple as some [sqlite](http://sqlite.org/), or interacting with some [RDBMS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Relational_database_management_system) like [PostGreSQL](http://postgresql.org/)). For things like birthdays and food preference, an `sqlite` database file is probably the good approach (see some [SQLite tutorial](http://www.sqlitetutorial.net/)). Put efforts in the good design of your [database schema](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_schema).

> This way, when I'll open it again, all those datas will still be saved there

Those datas will still be there if you keep them in some *outside* file (perhaps a simple `myappdata.sqlite` one). You can easily design your program to create that file if it does not exist (this happens only the first time you run your program; on the next runs, your program would successfully read that data from that outside file at startup).

In most current [operating systems](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Operating_system) (read [this textbook](http://pages.cs.wisc.edu/~remzi/OSTEP/) to learn more about OSes) notably Windows, MacOSX, Linux, Android, ..., the [executable](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Executable) is supposed to be read-only.  And it might be running in *several* [processes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Process_(computing)) at the same time (in such case, what should happen? Think of [ACID](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ACID_(computer_science)) properties).

**The usual practice is to store data *outside* of the executable** (most programs, including your text processor, your compiler, your web browser, ... are doing that). You don't explain why you want to store some data *inside* the executable, and doing so is unusual and highly operating system specific and executable format specific (for Linux, study carefully [elf(5)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man5/elf.5.html)...)

I would suggest to save the data in some *optional* file (or database) - its filepath could have some wired-in constant default, etc.... At startup, you check the existence of that data (e.g. with [access(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/access.2.html) on POSIX, or just by handling the failure case of `fopen` or `sqlite3_open` etc....). If it does not exist, you initialize your program data somehow. At exit (or save time), you write that data. BTW most programs are doing so.

Notice that on most operating systems and computers, a software is not simply a single executable file, but much more (e.g. required libraries and dependencies, configuration files, data files, [build automation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Build_automation) scripting such as [`Makefile`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Makefile), etc...). Its [installation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Installation_(computer_programs)) is a well identified technical process (sometimes a quite complex one), and [package managers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Package_manager) are helpful.

My feeling is that without specific motivation, **you should not even try to store** (mutable) **data** (persistently) **in your executable** (it is complex, brittle since very OS & compiler and build-chain specific, unusual, and opens [vulnerabilities](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vulnerability_(computing))).

For completeness, some programs did actually write some data by rewriting their executable. On Linux, [GNU `emacs`](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/) is doing that (in practice, only during its installation procedure) in its [`unexec.c`](https://github.com/typester/emacs/blob/master/src/unexec.c) file (very brittle, since OS & compiler specific) but that feature is [disputed](https://lwn.net/Articles/707615/) and is likely to disappear.

Many other systems deal cleverly with orthogonal persistence: [SBCL](http://sbcl.org/) has some [`save-lisp-and-die`](http://www.sbcl.org/manual/#Saving-a-Core-Image) primitive (it usually persists the state in some other "image" file). [Poly/ML](http://polyml.org/) has some [`export` facility](https://www.polyml.org/documentation/Reference/PolyMLStructure.html#export). J.Pitrat's CAIA system (see [this paper](https://pdfs.semanticscholar.org/2117/9600b3f05c0af399f9acbfc6e7b6d24daf03.pdf) and [his blog](http://bootstrappingartificialintelligence.fr/WordPress3); a 2016 [tarball of CAIA](http://starynkevitch.net/Basile/caia-su-24feb2016.tar.bz2) is available -with permission- on [my](http://starynkevitch.net/Basile/) home page) is able to regenerate entirely all its C code and all the required data (in thousands of files). [FullPliant](https://www.fullpliant.org/) is persisting its state in a well organized file tree. Such persistence or checkpointing techniques are tied to garbage collection (so you should then read the [*GC handbook*](http://gchandbook.org/)) and are using techniques and algorithms close to copying garbage collection.

FWIW, my current project, [bismon](https://github.com/bstarynk/bismon), is orthogonally persisting its entire heap, but do that outside of the main executable (in an ideal world, I would like to re-generate all the C or C++ source code of it; I am far from that goal).

My recommendation is to keep your software in several files: its executable, the C++ source code related to it, its data files (and probably much more dependencies, i.e. shared libraries or DLLs, font and image files, required binaries, etc...). Then you don't need to overwrite your executable when persisting your state. Since you mention C++ (which is *not* [homoiconic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Homoiconicity)), you could *generate* the C++ code of your system (then called a [Quine](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quine_(computing)) program) with its persistent data (and leave the recompilation of all that generated C++ to the system's C++ compiler). I also recommend to make your self-generating program some [free software](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Free_software). (if you do that, be nice to edit your question to gives its URL).

In C++, you might keep the data inside the executable (again, it is a *bad idea*, and I hope to have convinced you to avoid that approach) in the following way: You add one C or C++ source file (e.g. `mydata.cc`) which contains only data (e.g. some big `const char data[]="... many lines of data ...";`) - BTW, the [XBM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X_BitMap) file format could be inspirational. You keep all the other `*.o` [object files](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object_file) (in a place known to your program). To save data, you *regenerate* that `mydata.cc` file (with the new data for your current state) at each save operation, and at last you run the appropriate commands (perhaps using [std::system](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/program/system) in your code) to compile that `mydata.cc` and link it with the kept `*.o` into a fresh executable. So every save operation requires the recompilation of `data.cc` and its linking with other `*.o` object files (and of course the C++ compiler and linker, perhaps with additional build automation tools, becomes a required dependency of your program). Such an approach is not simpler than keeping an external data file (and requires to keep those `*.o` object files anyway).

> This way, when I'll open it again, all those datas will still be saved there

If your goal is just to get the data if it was written in the past, just keep the data in some *optional* database or file (as many programs do: your word processor would ask you to save its document before exiting if you start it without any document and write a few words in it) *outside* of your executable and write it before exiting your program. No need to overwrite your executable!

Answer (score 1):

What you want to do requires the ability to **write into** (and possibly read from) an executable **while it is running**. As far as I know this is not possible. 
While it is possible to change the behaviour of a running executable based on the user input which it is pre-conditioned to receive (think of a video game), it is not possible to store those inputs directly into the exe.

Video games store the progress, points of the player (which are the result of the inputs from the player) into a file(s) [outside the running .exe](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Saved_game).

So you will have to store the data in a file **outside** of the .exe file. 
I normally use google protocol buffers to do this. 
A good explanation of them can be found [here](https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/).

They are free, simple to use and supported for C++.

They are better than other formats like XML.
Some of the advantages are mentioned here

> Protocol buffers have many [advantages](https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/docs/overview) over XML for serializing structured data.

Protocol buffers:.

> 1. are simpler
> 2. are 3 to 10 times smaller
> 3. are 20 to 100 times faster
> 4. are less ambiguous
> 5. generate data access classes that are easier to use programmatically

Comment: Writing inside the executable might be *sometimes* possible but is usually a bad idea. See my answer

Comment: Saving the data in a `data.cc` file and recompiling it and linking it at every save operation is just like saving the data into a text file (with extension as .cc instead of .txt) and including it in the build. But would this be considered *saving data into the executable while it is running*? The data would become part of the executable only at the subsequent compilation and linking.

Comment: Of course. What makes you think I said something different? However, I did mention `emacs` way of  its `unexec.c`

Comment: Then we agree. I only said in my answer that this was not possible while the exe was still running.

Comment: But `emacs` shows the opposite. It *is* writing an ELF executable while running. I don't think the OP should even try that, but it is possible!

Answer (score 0):

## managing birth dates

As I explain in [my other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52026915/841108) (which you should read before this one), you don't want to save data *inside* your `.exe` file.
But I am guessing that you want to keep user birth date (and other data) from one run to the next. This answer focus mostly on that "users birth date" aspect and guesses that your question is some [XY problem](http://xyproblem.info/) (you really care about birth dates, not about overwriting an executable).

So, you decide to keep them somewhere (but *outside* of your executable). That could be a textual file; perhaps using [JSON](http://json.org/) or [YAML](http://yaml.org/) format, or some other textual [file format](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File_format) that you define properly, specified in [EBNF](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extended_Backus%E2%80%93Naur_form) notation in some document; or a binary file (perhaps protocol buffers as [suggested by P.W](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52027116/841108), or some [sqlite](http://sqlite.org/) "database file", or your own binary format that you need to document properly). It is very important to document properly the file format you are using.

Dealing with a textual file (whose format you have well defined) is easy with just fopen. You first need to define well defined a file path, perhaps as simple as

```
#define MYAPP_DATA_PATH "mydata.txt"
```

or better

```
const char* myapp_data_path = "mydata.txt";
```

(in reality, you better use some absolute file path to be able to run your program from various [working directories](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Working_directory), and provide some way to redefine it, e.g. thru program options, i.e. [command-line arguments](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/a/307472/40065))

You might also need to organize some data structure (a global variable `MyData global_data;` perhaps) keeping that data. In C++, you'll define some `class MyData;` and you want it to have at least member functions like `void MyData::add_birth_date(const std::string& person, const std::chrono::time_point& birthdate);` and `void MyData::remove_birth_date(const std::string& person);`. Probably you'll have more classes like `class Person;` etc...

### using textual format

So your application starts first by filling `global_data` *if* a file `mydata.txt` exists (otherwise, your `global_data` keeps its empty initial state). That is simple, you'll have some initialization function like:

```
void initial_fill_global_data(void) {
  std::ifstream input(myapp_data_path);
  // the file opening could have failed.... then we return immediately
  if (!input || !input.good() || input.fail()) 
     return;
```

Of course, you need to parse that `input`. Use well known [parsing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parsing) techniques that would call `global_data.add_birth_date` appropriately. Notice that for the JSON format, you'll find good C++ libraries (such as [jsoncpp](https://github.com/open-source-parsers/jsoncpp)) to make that really easy.

Before exiting your application, you should save that file. So you would call a `save_global_data`  function wich outputs into the `mydata.txt` file the contents of `MyData`. BTW, you could even register it with [`std::atexit`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/program/atexit).

The functions `initial_fill_global_data` and `save_global_data`  could be member functions (perhaps `static` ones) of your `MyData` class.

You might want your program to [lock](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File_locking) the data file. so that two processes running your program won't make havoc. This is operating system specific (e.g. [flock(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/flock.2.html) on Linux).

---

### using an [sqlite](http://sqlite.org/) database file

I also suggested to keep your data in an [sqlite](http://sqlite.org/) database file. Read some [sqlite tutorial](http://www.sqlitetutorial.net/) and refer to [sqlite C & C++ interface](https://www.sqlite.org/c3ref/intro.html) reference documentation. Then you need to think of a well designed [database schema](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_schema). And you don't need anymore to keep all the data in memory, since sqlite is capable of managing a [big amount](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/a/332071/40065) of data (many gigabytes), more that what fits in memory.

Obviously you need a global database pointer. So declare some global `sqlite3*db;`. Of course, `myapp_data_path` is now some `"mydata.sqlite"` path. Your `main`  starts by opening that (and creating an empty database if necessary) using

```
int opsta = sqlite3_open(myapp_data_path, &db);
if (opsta != SQLITE_OK) {
   std::cerr << "failed to open database " << myapp_data_path
             << " with error#" << opsta << "=" << sqlite_errstr(opsta) 
             << std::endl;
   exit (EXIT_FAILURE);
}
```

If the database did not exist, it is created empty. In that case, you need to define appropriate tables and indexes in it. My first suggestion could be something as simple as

```
char* errormsg = NULL;
int errcod = sqlite3_exec(db, 
    "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS data_table ("
    " name STRING NOT NULL UNIQUE,"
    " birthdate INT"
    ")", 
    &errormsg);
if (errcod != SQLITE_OK) { 
    std::cerr << "failed to create data_table " << errormsg << std::endl;
    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
}
```

Of course, you need to think of some more clever database schema (in reality you want *several* tables, some [database normalization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_normalization), and you should cleverly add [*indexes*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_index) on your tables), and to [prepare](https://www.sqlite.org/c3ref/prepare.html) the queries (transform them into `sqlite_stmt`-s) done in your program.

---

Obviously you should not save data inside your executable. In all my approaches above, your `myapp` program behaves as you want it to be. The first time it is running, it initialize some data -*outside* of the `myapp` executable- on the disk if that data was missing. The next times, it reuses and updates that data. But that `myapp` executable is never rewritten when running.